# Как создать музыкальный плеер на Java?

Tags: java, сервер, swing

есть идея создать музыкальный плеер на Java/Swing.
Суть будет вот в чем:
1)Можно будет проигрывать музыку на локальной машине.
2)Искать и загружать музыку из интернета.

Как можно реализовать 2 пункт?

Comment: Вопрос с поиском музыки непростой. Неужели будешь весь интернет прочёсывать? Это очень большая задача. Предлагаю сузить диапазон желаний и добавить конкретики.

Comment: А что если как нибудь подключаться к серверу zaycev.net и отправлять туда запросы на музыку.(я только учусь и многое что не понимаю)

Comment: Да, там есть возможность скачивать музыку. Скачиваешь страницу, находишь на ней ссылки для скачивания, качаешь. Чтобы не было громоздко, можешь попытаться скачать и распарсить с помощью Jsoup. Selenium всё-таки посложнее. Получив ссылки, качаешь (искать по Download a File From an URL in Java, примеров полно).

Comment: Понял , спасибо